# Using Bundler, RVM and RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I seem to be getting an odd issue here, not sure where to look to debug it. I have had Ruby installed on my machine for a while now but today have added RVM. So I will run through the steps I am taking:

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Try to install:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Installing rake (10.2.1) 
Gem::InstallError: rake requires Ruby version >= 1.9.
An error occured while installing rake (10.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Check Ruby version, which is greater than 1.9:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

Make sure rake is installed:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
rake (10.2.1)
...
```

Try installing rake anyway:

```
$ sudo gem install rake -v '10.2.1'
Successfully installed rake-10.2.1
Parsing documentation for rake-10.2.1
1 gem installed
```

Make sure rake is installed:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
rake (10.2.1)
...
```

Try again:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Installing rake (10.2.1) 
Gem::InstallError: rake requires Ruby version >= 1.9.
An error occured while installing rake (10.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Perhaps some useful information:

```
$ rvm info

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin ians-MacBook-Pro.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.9/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.22 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "3 hours 34 minutes 31 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/tools:/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/tools::/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was:

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.1.1
```

It seems as though, when I installed this version the first time round it didn't complete correctly and didn't update all the paths. So gem install was installing my gems in the wrong place.

Comment: Beat me to it. glad you solved your problem. For future reference, it can be handy to look at what's selected and what your default ruby is with `rvm list` and to set it to (e.g 2.1.1) with `rvm use 2.1.1`